# Pronunciation of interpoint when listing items

Tags: pronunciation, punctuation

```
話者の希望・意向を表す文や働きかけの文は来ない。
```

This is a case when interpoint (中黒) is used for listing like a conjunction.
I wonder how would a native speaker pronounce such an expression?

- Simply きぼういこう
- きぼう (pause) いこう
- or きぼうといこう, きぼうやいこう, i.e. inserting some context-appropriate conjunction word between items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 中黒 is used as punctuation and is only part of written language (文語体) and does not represent anything in spoken language (口語体). (You will find no 中黒 in bedtime stories.) When reading to yourself, or to someone reading the text next to you, the 中黒 would simply be ignored, with possibly a short pause between the words.

If you are reading, say, a dictionary entry out loud to someone not seeing the text, you can insert a や or と, as appropriate, to avoid mistaking the two words for a single one.

Comment: I think there might be a tendency to pronounce short (null-coordinated) lists with a steady rhythm.  For example, I think `１・２・３・４` might become `イチニーサンヨン`.  What do you think?

Comment: @snailboat Sounds reasonable. My answer is really "anything goes", as long as it sounds more like a list.

Comment: AFAIK 1,2,3,4 is usually read ["ichi ni san **shi**"](http://japangasm.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/ichi-ni-san-shi-go-roku-shichi-hachi/).

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I'd say it depends on what 4 counts: E.g. １・２・３・４部屋 should be イチニーサンヨンヘヤ.