# Are constructions like listing with 中黒 used in speech?

Tags: spoken-language, punctuation

Example: according to kotobank, one of the definitions of 滑る is

> 俗に、面白いことをしゃべろうとして失敗する。冗談・ギャグが受けない状態をいう。

I'm curious, are constructions like "冗談・ギャグ" used in speech? If they are, is it basically like taking a short pause while talking? And does it sound natural, formal or just plain weird?

Comment: kotobank.jp is just a platform providing access to various dictionaries. The definition you cited is from 大辞泉.

Comment: related (duplicate?) http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12903/pronunciation-of-interpoint-when-listing-items/12904#12904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be found in everyday speech. It can sometimes be expressed by using a pause or saying "なかぽつ" but this is generally used for quoting or reading off something exactly the way it is written. I would say it is much more common for a speaker to include とか or など to the same effect in colloquial speech. Saying なかぽつ can sound a bit tongue in cheek by being so precise with words.